# Can not preview the welcome page in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed laravel 4.2 in `http://localhost/laravel/varadha/`

According to Quick start guide of laravel if i visit `http://localhost/laravel/varadha/`, i should get a welcome message. but i am getting this message.

Index of /laravel/varadha   Name    Last modified   Size    Description

```
Parent Directory         -   
CONTRIBUTING.md     22-Jun-2014 20:28   146      
app/    22-Jun-2014 20:28    -   
artisan     22-Jun-2014 20:28   2.4K     
bootstrap/  22-Jun-2014 20:28    -   
composer.json   22-Jun-2014 20:28   697      
composer.lock   22-Jun-2014 20:28    58K     
laravel-master/     22-Jun-2014 20:30    -   
phpunit.xml     22-Jun-2014 20:28   567      
public/     22-Jun-2014 20:28    -   
server.php  22-Jun-2014 20:28   519      
vendor/     22-Jun-2014 20:29    -
```

I am using wamp server.

PHP 5.4.29.

MYSQl 5.5.8

Apache 2.2.17

Answer (score 0):

You have pointed your server www folder to `/laravel/varadha`

You need to point it to `/laravel/varadha/public`

Comment: I clicked public now i am getting this Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\laravel\varadha\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 2874

Comment: Just use Laravel Homestead with Vagrant. There is really no reason to use WAMP anymore. http://laravel.com/docs/homestead